# An inequality for sumsets

Tags: reference-request, additive-combinatorics, sumset

Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ and let $m \geq 1$ be an integer such that $|A| < N^{1/m}$. I'm wondering if anyone has seen a good upper bound for the sum 
$$
S_m(A) = \sum_{k=1}^m|kA|,
$$
where $kA := A + \cdots + A$, $k$ times. Note there is the trivial bound $S_m(A) \leq \sum_{k=1}^m|A|^k$. But can we do better?

Comment: You cannot in general: it can happen that all sums $a_1+\dotsb+a_m$ are pairwise distinct (unless obtained from each other by permuting the terms), in this case your $S_m(A)$ will be close to $|A|^m/m!$ which is of the same order of magnitude as $\sum_{k=1}^m |A|^k$.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_n$ do you mean $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}n$?